# Breaking multiple values in an attribute into multiple lines?

Tags: html, coding-style, markup

Let me explain by example:

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">

    ...

</html>
```

As you can see, the `prefix` attribute in the `html` tag has multiple definitions. How do I break them into multiple lines? (Considering that a line break is equivalent a space when minified back into a single line... it's kinda tough.)

Is this considered normal?

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="
    og: http://ogp.me/ns#
    fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#
    article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#
">
```

**EDIT:** Facebook does it like this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix=
    "og: http://ogp.me/ns#
    fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#
    article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
```

Comment: Breaking the HTML tag to multiple lines like that is goignt o cause you problems in some browsers.

Comment: In most of the browsers it would be fine, but what is the need for this?

Comment: @RaunakKathuria Beautifying the long code.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute values are different. Each whitespace character is stored in the DOM. Whether the difference matters depends on the definition of the attribute. Many attributes, such as `class`, are defined as taking a set of whitespace-separated tokens as value, and for them, the amount and type of whitespace characters between tokens, or before the first token and after the last token, does not matter.

The `prefix` attribute is not present in HTML specifications or drafts. The relevant specification is [RDFa Core 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/), which defines the `prefix` attribute as
“a white space separated list of prefix-name IRI pairs” and contains examples like

```
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  prefix="foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
          dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  >
```

So for the `prefix` attribute, formatting as in the question is acceptable. (Whether it is “normal” in a sense other than “conforming” is a matter of opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's all that "normal". In general, like the comments to your question suggest, it's technically possible but you're opening your page up to (unnecessary) potential parsing errors.

Look to the [HTML WG's example regarding using newlines in the `title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#attr-title) as a concrete example of this.

Furthermore, I was unable to find/remember a single case where I'd seen this used on purpose, with the exception of SVG (but that's not technically HTML).

However, if you run this sample through the [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it'll pass with no errors or warnings in regards to multi-line attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="
    og: http://ogp.me/ns#
    fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#
    article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#
">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Generally, it's better to be safe than sorry. Since I couldn't find any examples to the contrary in this case, I'd venture to say that other developers would agree *(Do by all means correct me if I'm wrong)*.

Comment: I have seen an example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/ -- But I didn't like it, hence the question.

Comment: @its_me You're right. Well, I'd venture to say that it's only done for readability in that particular case (Like the extra spaces in the `meta` tags).